# Bind Silverlight listbox to a List<>

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to bind a Silverlight ListBox to a `List<Products>` collection - ProductName. I want to show the ProductName when the user selects an item in the Listbox. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbProductList"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="ProductName" 
         SelectedValuePath="ProductId"
          />
```

Set the datacontext of the listbox to the productlist:

```
lbProductList.DataContext = myProductList;
```

Event better would be to define a ViewModel with the productList and the selected product. The you could bind the SelectedValue as well:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

To display the selected Product you could do with element binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ProductName, ElementName=lbProductList}" />
```